# How to mapping file in a folder with a file as a pattern using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, file, directory, mapping

I have some folder like this:
FolderABC
FolderDEF

Inside those folder, I have 2 kind of files, one file is identifier and another file is that the file that I need to get. I want to get a file where the identifier match with what I need.

I tried this

```
$Directory= "D:\Prject" #inside this folder consist of those 2 folder above (FolderABC.FolderDEF)
$MyIdentifier = "CODE123"
$ExtensionFileToGet = "*.txt"

$FindFile = (Get-Item (Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory\*\$ExtensionFileToGet | Select-String -Pattern "$MyIdentifier").Path).Directory.FullName
$FindFile
```

But it does not return all the file in that folder. My expectation I can get the files from the folder where the identifier exist in that folder.

Anyone can help me please. Thank you.

The folder root example:

```
FolderABC
[
[
  file.txt
  file2.txt
  CODE123

FolderABC
[
[
  file.txt
  file2.txt
  CODE456
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the file when you "get" it? Is the Identifier part of the filename or text inside it? Let's _start_ by correcting the Get-ChildItem command, it should be `Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Filter $ExtensionFileToGet -Recurse` to retrieve all text files.

Comment: @Ash I want to use those file to rename it in another process. I update he question with the folder structure.

Comment: So is the CODE*** file a txt file too or not? It's not clear why the filter should be for .txt files, but your example gives the files no extension. Do you just want the name of those CODE*** files? Are they always the word CODE followed by three digits?

Comment: @Ash CODE *** is a file. Because I want to get only .txt file, but I use file CODE*** as identifier which folder that I need.